# How to convert multiple string into arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, arraylist

I m new in android.I want to add these String variables to ArrayList, what I am doing now.
Suppose I have a four of String Variables.....

```
String number = "9876543211";
String type = "incoming";
String date = "1/1/2016";
String duration = "45 sec";
```

Here is my java code.......

```
while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
    String number = managedCursor.getString(number1);
    String type2 = managedCursor.getString(type1);
    String date = managedCursor.getString(managedCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")).toString();
    java.util.Date date1 = new java.util.Date(Long.valueOf(date));
    String duration = managedCursor.getString(duration1);
    String type = null;

    String fDate = date1.toString();

    int callcode = Integer.parseInt(type2);

    sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + number + "");
    sb.append(" \nCall Type:--- " + type + " ");
    sb.append("\nCall Date:--- " + fDate + "");
    sb.append("\nCall duration in sec :--- " + duration);
    sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
}
```

Comment: If these pieces of data are unrelated, you should instead create a class to encapsulate these values, rather than an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Use 

HashMap<String,String> hashmap=new Map<String,String>();
hashmap.put("number",number);
hashmap.put("type",type);
hashmap.put("date",date);
hashmap.put("duration",duration);

it will be easy to get your values by using key. or Use Model class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 4castle suggest, you should really have a custom class - which looking at the properties you are interested in, you might want to name "CallLogEntry" and then have properties for this class. Here is an example of such a custom class.

```
public class CallLogEntry {
  String number;
  String type;
  String date;
  String duration; //this should ideally be of type Long (milliseconds)  

      public CallLogEntry(){
       //do stuff if necessary for no-params constructor
      }

      public CallLogEntry(String number, String type, String date, String duration){
        this.number = number;
        this.type = type;
        this.date = date;
        this.duration = duration;
      }

      //getters and setters go here..
      getNumber(){ return this.number;}
      setNumber(String number){ this.number = number;}
      //...the rest of them...
    }
```

Than it makes more sense to have an ArrayList of CallHistoryEntry items like this:

```
//...declare list of call-log-entries:
List<CallLogEntry> callLogEntryList = new  ArrayList<CallLogEntry>();
//...add entries 
CallLogEntry entry = new CallLogEntry(number, type, date, duration);
callLogEntryList.add(entry);
```

The advantage of doing it like this, especially in an Android app, is that later you may pass this list to some list-adapter for a list-view.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank for response @ishmaelMakitla....I have allready make arraylist i wont to insert this into mysql database.

Comment: OK, inserting into the database is out of scope of your current question - my suggestion is that you either accept one of the answers (so your question is marked off as answered) or you remove it. You can then as a separate question about inserting data into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Create JavaBean Class as follows

```
public class DataBean {

    String number;
    String type;
    String date;
    String duration;

    public DataBean(String number, String type, String date, String duration) {
        this.number = number;
        this.type = type;
        this.date = date;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}
```

**Now create Arryalist as follows**

```
ArrayList<DataBean> dataBeanList = new ArrayList<>();
DataBean dataBean=new DataBean(number,type,date,duration);
dataBeanList.add(dataBean);//added bean object arrylist
```

**For Retrieving data do as follow**

// iterate through arraylist as follows

```
 for(DataBeand d: dataBeanList ){
        if(d.getName() != null && d.getDate()!=null)
           //something here
    }
```

Comment: Thank for response @Rissmon Suresh....I have allready make arraylist i wont to insert this into mysql database.

Comment: for that you need to call webservice https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit